# what's a good file structure for projects using gulp and mocha?

Tags: node.js, gulp, mocha.js

Question -- What is a good file structure for a small projects using Gulp and Mocha? All of my gulp and test files are all in the root folder floating around and I know I should separate them into folders, I'm looking for good examples of how to do that for these specific tools.

```
/rootFolder
    /.git
    /node_modules
    eslinrtrc.js
    .gitignore
    app.js
    gulpfile.js
    index.html
    package.json
    test.js
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I'm using something like this and it's very usefull to me:

```
/node_modules
/src
  app.js
  index.html
/tools
  /gulp
     gulpfile.js
  /mocha
     test.js
package.json
eslinrtrc.js
```

TL;DR: I'm making a tools folder with a subfolder for every tool I'm using, in your case gulp and mocha and add the files in the subfolders ;)

Hack tip: Replace gulp with npm scripts, you'll see that is totally worth it ;)